# Как трансформировать линию

Tags: javascript, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Есть код, я уже научился находить начальную и конечную точку, понял как рисовать линию, но я не понимаю как правильно обращаться с трансформацией. Я собираюсь рисовать линию таким образом, как на изображении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблемы:**
1) Нужно как-то по особому считать, как поворачивать угол при `transform : rotate()`, я не понимаю как это происходит, возможно нужно поменять начальную точку трансформации для этого
2) `transform: scale()`неприятно сжимает прямую и она не ровно выпрямляется
при анимации
3) Если угол поворачивать в разные стороны(лево и право), то `transform: scale()` меняет сжатие по `x` и `y` на противоположные.
Я хочу разобраться, как работает эта штука, почему `scale` всё сбивает, как написать зависимость между `scale` и `rotate`

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame       ||
           mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
           msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

  let start = performance.now();

  reqAnimFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}

function createPath(from, to) {

 function elemPosition(elem) {
  let pos = {
      top: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      left: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      right: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      bottom: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  };
  return pos;
 }

 function centerElem(elem) {
  let width = elem.offsetWidth;
  let height = elem.offsetHeight;
  let centerX = width/2 + elemPosition(elem).left;
  let centerY = height/2 + elemPosition(elem).top;
  let pos = {
   y: centerY,
   x: centerX
  };
  return pos;
 }

 function render(childF, childT) {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('harmony');
  document.body.append(div);

  let start = {
   x: centerElem(childF).x,
   y: elemPosition(childF).bottom
  }; // координаты начальной точки

  let final = {
   x: centerElem(childT).x,
   y: elemPosition(childT).top
  }; // координаты конечной точки


  let height = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).height; // исходная высота прямой
  height = Number(height.slice(0, height.length-2)); // исходная высота прямой
  let d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((final.x - start.x), 2) + Math.pow((final.y - start.y), 2) ); // длина прямой после анимации
  let angle = Math.atan( (final.y-start.y) / (final.x-start.x) ) * 180 / Math.PI; // угол в градусах
  let scale = d/height; // насколько масштабировать прямую по высоте


  animate({
    duration: 5000,
    timing(timeFraction) {
      return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
      div.style.transform = `
          translate(${start.x-3.5}px, ${start.y}px)
          scale(${progress*scale}, 1)
          rotate(${-(90-angle)}deg)
          translateZ(0)`;
    }
  });



 }

 let childFrom = from.children[0];
 let childTo = to.children[0];

 centerElem(childFrom);
 render(childFrom, childTo);

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 createPath(items[0], items[4]);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.line:not(:first-child) {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 2%;
}

.item__img {
 z-index: 2;
}

.item__img:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.line {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.harmony {
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 transform: scale(1, 1) translateZ(0);
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="line line__one">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__one -->

 <div class="line line__two">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__two -->

 <div class="line line__three">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__three -->


</div> <!-- .wrapper -->
```

Если просто попробовать вместо `transform: scale` использовать `height`, то всё работает как надо:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
  return requestAnimationFrame       ||
         mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
         webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
         oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
         msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  }
})();

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

  let start = performance.now();

  reqAnimFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}

function createPath(from, to) {

  function elemPosition(elem) {
    let pos = {
      top: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      left: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      right: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      bottom: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
    };
    return pos;
  }

 function centerElem(elem) {
    let width = elem.offsetWidth;
    let height = elem.offsetHeight;
    let centerX = width/2 + elemPosition(elem).left;
    let centerY = height/2 + elemPosition(elem).top;
    let pos = {
      y: centerY,
      x: centerX
    };
    return pos;
 }

 function render(childF, childT) {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('harmony');
  document.body.append(div);

  let start = {
   x: centerElem(childF).x,
   y: elemPosition(childF).bottom
  }; // координаты начальной точки

  let final = {
   x: centerElem(childT).x,
   y: elemPosition(childT).top
  }; // координаты конечной точки


  let height = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).height; // исходная высота прямой
  height = Number(height.slice(0, height.length-2)); // исходная высота прямой
  let d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((final.x - start.x), 2) + Math.pow((final.y - start.y), 2) ); // длина прямой после анимации
  let angle = Math.atan( (final.y-start.y) / (final.x-start.x) ) * 180 / Math.PI; // угол в градусах
  let scale = d/height; // насколько масштабировать прямую по высоте

  animate({
    duration: 5000,
    timing(timeFraction) {
      return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
        div.style.left = `${start.x-3.5}px`;
        div.style.top = `${start.y}px`;
        div.style.transform = `rotate(${-(90-angle)}deg) translateZ(0)`;
        div.style.height = `${d*progress}px`;
    }
  });

 }

 let childFrom = from.children[0];
 let childTo = to.children[0];

 centerElem(childFrom);
 render(childFrom, childTo);

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 createPath(items[0], items[4]);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.line:not(:first-child) {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 2%;
}

.item__img {
 z-index: 2;
}

.item__img:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.line {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.harmony {
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 transform: scale(1, 1) translateZ(0);
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="line line__one">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__one -->

 <div class="line line__two">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__two -->

 <div class="line line__three">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__three -->


</div> <!-- .wrapper -->
```

Comment: Миша тут можно вообще svg path рисовать при scroll

Comment: @MaximLensky  и кода будет 40 строчек

Comment: @StrangerintheQ за то дорого будет выглядеть

Comment: @MaximLensky конечно можно, но я хочу разобраться как работает transform, закономерность то есть, её надо только найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже transform сначала выполняет поворот(в вашем коде) потом масштабирование по оси х, по этому я поменял местами, кое что, и стало работать как надо.

```js
draw(progress) {
  div.style.transform = `translate(${start.x-3.5}px, ${start.y}px)
                         rotate(${-(90-angle)}deg)
                         scale(1, ${progress*scale})
                         translateZ(0)`;
}
```

вот измененный код полностью, работает идентично вашему второму варианту.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame       ||
           mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
           msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

  let start = performance.now();

  reqAnimFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}

function createPath(from, to) {

 function elemPosition(elem) {
  let pos = {
      top: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      left: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      right: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      bottom: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  };
  return pos;
 }

 function centerElem(elem) {
  let width = elem.offsetWidth;
  let height = elem.offsetHeight;
  let centerX = width/2 + elemPosition(elem).left;
  let centerY = height/2 + elemPosition(elem).top;
  let pos = {
   y: centerY,
   x: centerX
  };
  return pos;
 }

 function render(childF, childT) {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('harmony');
  document.body.append(div);

  let start = {
   x: centerElem(childF).x,
   y: elemPosition(childF).bottom
  }; // координаты начальной точки

  let final = {
   x: centerElem(childT).x,
   y: elemPosition(childT).top
  }; // координаты конечной точки


  let height = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).height; // исходная высота прямой
  height = Number(height.slice(0, height.length-2)); // исходная высота прямой
  let d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((final.x - start.x), 2) + Math.pow((final.y - start.y), 2) ); // длина прямой после анимации
  let angle = Math.atan( (final.y-start.y) / (final.x-start.x) ) * 180 / Math.PI; // угол в градусах
  let scale = d/height; // насколько масштабировать прямую по высоте


  animate({
    duration: 5000,
    timing(timeFraction) {
      return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
      div.style.transform = `
          translate(${start.x-3.5}px, ${start.y}px)
          rotate(${-(90-angle)}deg)
          scale(1 ,${progress*scale})
          translateZ(0)`;
    }
  });



 }

 let childFrom = from.children[0];
 let childTo = to.children[0];

 centerElem(childFrom);
 render(childFrom, childTo);

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 createPath(items[0], items[4]);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.line:not(:first-child) {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 2%;
}

.item__img {
 z-index: 2;
}

.item__img:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.line {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.harmony {
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 transform: scale(1, 1) translateZ(0);
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="line line__one">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__one -->

 <div class="line line__two">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__two -->

 <div class="line line__three">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__three -->


</div> <!-- .wrapper -->
```

Comment: Очень интересно, никогда бы об этом не подумал :D

Comment: Есть одна проблема, с размером окна, нужно пересчитывать трансформацию

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да, я работаю над этим, переписываю код, чтобы можно было ресайзить код и заново не анимировать это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1068713/331312